# How can I get state data inside React Actions Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an action which calls another function which needs some state data. I cannot pass that state data t the action because the function will be dispatching/updating the state so it will be an infinite loop. Instead I would like to get access to the global store I have.

Actions

```
export function handleCustomersExtraFunctionality() {
  return function (dispatch) {
   Call another function(stateData)
   //How can I get access to the stateData inside an action creater function
}
```

My component calls handleCustomersExtraFunctionality but I cannot pass the state because it will be updated in this function which in turn calls my component again. So I am looking to access the state data.
What is the best way to access state data whenever I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux passes a second parameter to all action creators called `getState`. This is itself a function which you can call to get the global state object at that instant:

```js
export function handleCustomersExtraFunctionality() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const currentState = getState();
    // Do what you want with current state
    dispatch({ type: SOME_TYPE, payload });
  }
}
```